# How to change audio via script? UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can you tell me how to change audio track via script in Unity?

Example:

```
int x = 5;

if (x == 5)
{
   //CHANGE AUDIO TRACK
}
```

Comment: Well somewhere you setup a track and played it. Set a different audio clip and olay thet instead. Very well documented

Comment: I setup the track by Unity Editor and now I wanna change it by script.

Comment: Ok so how did you set it up? Unity documentation is very thorough tbh

Comment: I said that I setup the track by "Unity UI" , i don't know how call it.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a reference to your audio source as well as the audio clip you're trying to play. After that it should be as simple as:

```
audioSource.clip = audioClip;
audioSource.Play();
```